# UITabBarController subclass methods not available on child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to call a custom method on my `UITabBarController` subclass from within one of the child view controllers. I have instantiated my `CustomTabBarController` class as the root view controller in `AppDelegate.swift`, however, the `.tabBarController` property on my child view controllers is of the class `UITabBarController` instead of `CustomTabBarController`.

Why does this happen?  Is it possible to have the `.tabBarController` property on my view controllers reflect my subclass instead of the default `UITabBarController` class?

Here is my subclass:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, LoginControllerDelegate {

  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    setupViews()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    checkLoginStatus()
  }

  func checkLoginStatus() {
    if defaults.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == false {
      let loginController = LoginController()
      loginController.delegate = self
      present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

  func loginControllerDidDismiss() {
    print("Delegation is working...")
  }

  func setupViews() {
    let homeController = HomeController()
    homeController.tabBarItem = CustomTabBarItem(title: "Home", imageNames: ["courthouse-icon-unselected", "courthouse-icon"])
    let homeNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    homeNavController.navigationBar.applyCustomStyle()

    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.34, blue:0.65, alpha:1.00)
    self.setViewControllers([homeNavController], animated: true)
  }

  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    print(viewController.title)
    return true
  }

}
```

In my view controller, I would like to access this class like so:

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: ListController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Home"
    self.tabBarController??? // Right now this is a UITabBarController, but I would like to it be a CustomTabBarController 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to test whether it's what you believe it to be and cast it so that the compiler knows the correct class.

e.g.:

```
    if let custom = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController {
        custom.checkLoginStatus()
    } else {
        print("Unexpected controller \(self.tabBarController)")
    }
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try casting it as the correct class. It makes a lot of sense, and for my use case it works perfectly!  Thanks!